# Cannot create an object of type 'System.Int32' from its string representation '3.2' for the 'CurrentRating' property

Tags: c#, ajaxcontroltoolkit

```
<ajax:Rating ID="rating" runat="server" MaxRating="5" CurrentRating="3.2" 
CssClass="rstar" StarCssClass="ritem" WaitingStarCssClass="svd" 
FilledStarCssClass="fld" EmptyStarCssClass="empt"  AutoPostBack="True"
```

get me error:

> Cannot create an object of type
>   'System.Int32' from its string
>   representation '3.2' for the
>   'CurrentRating' property.

C# code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!Page.IsPostBack)
            {
                Rating(rating.CurrentRating);
            }
          }

 private void Rating(double value)
        {
            Label1.Text = "Selected value  " + EvalRating(value, rating.MaxRating, rt_min, rt_max);
        }

        private static string EvalRating(double value, int maxvalue, int minrange, int maxrange)
        {
            int stepDelta = (minrange == 0) ? 1 : 0;
            double delta = (double)(maxrange - minrange) / (maxvalue - 1);
            double result = delta * value - delta * stepDelta;
            return FormatRes(result);
        }

        private static string FormatRes(double value)
        {
            return String.Format("{0:g}", value);
        }

        protected void rating_Changed(object sender, AjaxControlToolkit.RatingEventArgs e)
        {
            Rating(int.Parse(e.Value));
        }
```

Comment: What class does object `rating` instantiate in C# code and what type does property `CurrentRating` have in that class?

Answer (score 4):

"3.2" isn't an int value, but a double.  Try changing the `rating_Changed` logic to:

```
Rating(double.Parse(e.Value));
```

Comment: thx for such a fast help but i still get Cannot create an object of type 'System.Int32' from its string representation '3.2' for the 'CurrentRating' property.

Comment: @senzacionale: What line gives you that error message, now?  This was the only integer conversion in the code you displayed...

Comment: this line: <ajax:Rating ID="rating" runat="server" MaxRating="5" CurrentRating="3.2"

Comment: @senzacionale: You didn't post that code - but make sure "CurrentRating" is a **double**, not an int.

Comment: @senzacionale See comment to your question. I'm not familiar with AJAX and maybe it's silly, but in C# you have `Rating(rating.CurrentRating);`. So what class does `rating` object instantiate and where from it knows what is `CurrentRating`?